# looping through inner articles xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I'm having trouble looping through this HTML in my xpath as below. The goal would be to loop through the `article` elements and then inside that once again the inner `article` elements. **I think the problem is my inner query against the inner article elements**

I have an HTML as follows:

```
 <div id="content">
   <article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
   </article>
   <article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
   </article>
</div>
```

I have my xpath code as follows:

```
$articlesxpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/article');
foreach($articlesxpath as $item){
  $items = $item->query('./article');
  foreach($items as $ix){
   var_dump($ix);
  }
```

}

As you can see, im trying to loop through the articles and then inside that element the inner article elements. **The goal would be to get the information from the inner article elements**

Not sure whats wrong with my code.

Comment: And what is wrong? We should quess?

Comment: @u_mulder updated question

Comment: I see the goal, but I don't see __what is wrong__

Comment: @u_mulder updated

Comment: @jkushner what is your expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati I want all of the anchor href values which exist inside the article elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To narrow xpath query pass second argument to `query`:

```
$articlesxpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/article');
foreach($articlesxpath as $item){
    // search in $item node
    $items = $xpath->query('article', $item);
    foreach($items as $ix) {
        var_dump($ix->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
$articlesxpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/article/article');
foreach($articlesxpath as $item){
    var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
```

To get an href from `a` (and **not** from `article`) you should create a **proper query**:

```
$articlesxpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/article/article/div/h2/a');
foreach($articlesxpath as $item){
    var_dump($item->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

And here's a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), make sure you're familiar with it's text.

Comment: How do I get the anchor hrefs from each article anchor

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed html template then you query `DOMDocument` like this

**XPath query:** `//div[@id="content"]/article/article/div/h2/a`

```
<?php

$string = '<html><body><div id="content">
   <article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
   </article>
   <article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2><a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome2</a></h2>
           </div>
        </article>
   </article>
</div></body></html>';
$obj = new DOMDocument();
$obj->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($obj);
$articlesxpath = $xpath->query('//div[@id="content"]/article/article/div/h2/a');
foreach ($articlesxpath as $item)
{
    print_r($item->getAttribute("href"));
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

```
hrefvalue
hrefvalue
hrefvalue
hrefvalue
hrefvalue
hrefvalue
```